# Why does reading continue in a FIFO after the writing end is closed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipe, ipc, named-pipes

I have 2 python programs. One is the reader

```py
fifo_read=open('buffer','r')
while True:
    data=fifo_read.read(1)
    print('"',data,'"read from buffer')
```

and the other is the writer

```py
import time

fifo_write=open('./buffer','w')

while True:
    fifo_write.write('a')
    fifo_write.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

The problem that I am facing is, as soon as I terminate the writer with Ctrl+C, the reader continues reading "" from the FIFO. For my purposes, I want the reader to block until another writer starts sometime in the future and starts writing to the FIFO. But this is not happening in this case.

Comment: What do you expect read to do when you get to the end of the file?  Also, why do you call it FIFO read, you're just opening a file.

Comment: Read returns an emtpy string when you're at the end of your "file/device" so you need to check for an empty string. There are tools in the link I provided for doing that. https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipc.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python read named PIPE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39089776/python-read-named-pipe)

Answer (score -1):

This is a legacy design defect that is not present in MacOS.

In early days, FIFO is designed for communication between 1 reader program and 1 writer program. So to simplify things, once the writer closes, the reader will start to receive "" in a loop, a behavior similar to sockets. In addition, when the writer closes, `select.select()` continues to return the FIFO as available for reading (but in fact it keeps returning ""), which is incorrect. As a workaround, you have to close and reopen the FIFO. If some day Linus Torvalds realizes this and fixes it in the Linux kernel, the whole world would be happy ^_^