# Python - How to exit the loop when data pipe has no incoming data?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, embedded, embedded-linux

I have been trying to write a python script that prints the first 10 lines of the CAN Bus data that is coming from a data pipe. The code works well when there is data in the pipe, but doesn't break out of the loop when no data.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
import os
import re
with open('/var/run/regen/can0/rx', 'r') as pse:  #/var/run/regen/can0/rx is the data pipe
        count = 0
        for line in pse:
            if " " in line:
                break          #want to exit the loop when there is no data
            else:
                while count < 10:
                    for line in pse:
                        words = list(filter(None, re.split(r"[()\[\]\s]\s*", line)))
                        print(words)
                        count += 1
                        break
            break
```

**Summary ---
Works - Prints first 10lines when data is coming through the pipe
Doesn't work - The loop doesn't break when there is no data in the pipe**

I tried using a timer to exit the loop, but it doesn't work as well. The loop doesn't exit when the time given is complete.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
import os
import time
t_end = time.time() + 0.2
while time.time() < t_end:
    with open('/var/run/regen/can0/rx', 'r') as pse:
    # --- remaining code ----
```

**Can anyone tell me how to check if a data pipe has any data incoming or not? **

Comment: Did you try to check what is the value of `line` when there is no data in the pipe?

Comment: There is no output when there is no data. Its blank

Comment: So I think it is just your condition is wrong - you are checking for a space in the data, not blank. Notice the difference between what you wrote: `" "`, and the empty string `""`

Comment: I tried this now. Still doesn't exit out of the loop.. maybe no data isn't equal to just a blank?

Comment: Try to check what the type of `line` and if it equals something specific (perhaps `None`?)
If you are familiar with `ipdb` package, you can use it to set a break in your code for debugging purposes.

Comment: Im printing the output on the terminal. When there is no data, there is no standard output. Not sure if `line` is `None`. Is there a way to check if a pipe has any incoming data or not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if stdin has some data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762881/how-do-i-check-if-stdin-has-some-data)

Comment: maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39089776/python-read-named-pipe

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762881/how-do-i-check-if-stdin-has-some-data) thread.

Answer taken from there, this might work for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
import os
import re
import sys

with open('/var/run/regen/can0/rx', 'r') as pse:  #/var/run/regen/can0/rx is the data pipe
    if not pse.isatty():
        count = 0
        for line in pse:
            words = list(filter(None, re.split(r"[()\[\]\s]\s*", line)))
            print(words)
            count += 1
```

This works to end the loop in my test file:

```
import sys

if not sys.stdin.isatty():
  for line in sys.stdin:
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

When I run

```
echo "hello" | python pipe.py  # outputs: hello
```

however

```
python pipe.py  # outputs nothing, but ends the script
```

used to hang, but now the script finishes after I added the `isatty()`

However, since you open the pipe as a file, I think you can use traditional file reading logic. So I believe you shouldn't need the pse.isatty() line at all. I think this should work too:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
import os
import re

with open('/var/run/regen/can0/rx', 'r') as pse:  #/var/run/regen/can0/rx is the data pipe
    count = 0
    for line in pse:
        words = list(filter(None, re.split(r"[()\[\]\s]\s*", line)))
        print(words)
        count += 1
```

I skipped the while and extra for loop, that was hanging the script when I tried.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the comment. I tried your script but it breaks out in all conditions. As in, it breaks out when there is incoming data in the pipe & does the same when there is no data as well. Is there a way to check if the data pipe has incoming stream of data? i tried methods from the link you have attached, still it doesn't work.

Comment: oh right.. that's because my solution is garbage XD I'm just checking stdin, but you are not using stdin.. I modified it, try it now

Comment: I'm assuming you run your script periodically to check the pipe in my answer, but even if that's not the case, hopefully it still works then with the isatty line

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the edit. But, it still doesn't work ( Doesn't exit the loop when there is no data). I think the data pipe is waiting for the input before proceeding with any execution.

Comment: I'm gonna need more info about your setup then, how is data piped to `/var/run/regen/can0/rx`? I need to be able to reproduce the issue

Comment: also, how do you run your script? (the one you posted) how is it scheduled?