High latency while Running python code using bash script in a python program due to imports
I have a python application which uses subprocesses to run a bash script. The bash script in turn runs a python file which has some imports (retina face, deep face libraries). The application takes a lot of time to run because each time the subprocess is run, it takes 20-30 secs to load/import retina/deep face modules. Is there a way by which this can be sped up?
Note: Changing the set-up is not possible i.e. I can't call the python code directly from the original python code.
I am unsure on how to go about solving this, any help is appreciated. Thank you.
I tried using cached version of sys modules but that did not work. Although, I am unsure on how to correctly utilize it.

Why are you able to run the second script as bash with propably the same interpreter as the first or at least on the same machine but can not import a function of it into the first script?

One way is to load the Python file with the heavy imports once and keep it open. Then, every time the Bash script runs it can send a message to the already running script to start processing.
To communicate with the running Python script from Bash there are various methods. One easy and flexible way might be to use a named pipe. This is a special type of file that causes Python to wait for input when you read it.
The following is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/55734712/:
import pathlib
import os
# heavy imports here

FIFO = 'myfifo'
# remove pipe in case it exists
pathlib.Path(FIFO).unlink(missing_ok=True)
# create new pipe
os.mkfifo(FIFO)

def do_something(msg):
    print(f"open {msg} and process it")

while True:
    with open(FIFO) as fifo:
        for line in fifo:
            msg = line.strip()
            do_something(msg)

Now you can write to the pipe from Bash. Make sure the Bash script has the same working directory as the Python script, or provide the full path to the pipe. Note that you need to end the line explicitly with \n.
printf "somefile.jpg\n" > myfifo

This causes the Python script to print
open somefile.jpg and process it

and then the while True loop causes the script to wait for further input.
